# Как достать значение object_id в подобном объекте?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть объект
{"response":{"object_id":233178233,"type":"user"}}
Из него нужно достать значение object_id
Помогите, пожалуйста, уже часа полтора ломаю голову...
Я получаю этот объект через GET запрос
$j.ajax({
url: '/resolveScreenName?access_token=' + token + '&screen_name=' + val,
type: "GET",
success: function(result){
console.log(result)
}
})
В result получаю этот самый объект. Так, вот, как мне получить object_id?

Comment: Попробуйте начать с чтения книг по языку JavaScript

Comment: Я в принципе знаю, как достать, но всё-равно получаю в ответе undefined. Я не знаю, с чем это связано, поэтому и прошу помощи здесь.
Я пытался так:
result.response.object_id

Comment: Покажи как пытался достать. Скорее всего ты пытался это сделать вне аякса. Где нибудь за пределами функции

Comment: Нет, я это делал в самом аяксе.
вместо success: function(result) {
console.log(result)
}
делал
success: function(result) {
console.log(result.response.object_id)
}

т.к. просто result выдаёт объект с объектами

Comment: Код верный. Так что либо ты опечатался, либо это не полный объект.

Comment: Спасибо большое за попытку помочь, я уже разобрался. Просто в API Express.js изменил GET запрос и всё заработало :) Хорошего вечера!)